# How to align the text in a Bootstrap 3 Jumbotron all the way to the left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to have the text in my Jumbotron (Bootstrap 3) all the way to the left.
I tried padding and align but nothing seems to work: there's always a distance between the left-beginning of the Jumbotron background and the text.

I tried adding to a custom css file:

```
.jumbotron {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Top and bottom work. Left doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of Bootstrap css style:

```
.container .jumbotron {
padding-left: 60px;
}
```

Try to override it.

Comment: Please see the CSS code I just added. Missing container? But top and bottom work! Where am I wrong?

Comment: Strangely, it works fine for me, try padding-left: 0px !important;

Answer (score 1):

You are falling prey to CSS specificity based on [descendant combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators). Basically `.container .jumbotron{...}` carries more weight than `.jumbotron{...}` alone, so easiest thing is to override it with

```
.container .jumbotron {
padding:0px 3px;
}
```

However, there are a number of descendant combinators within jumbotron, (h1-6, .h1-6, p, etc) you have to watch out for... To see this in action, throw an `h1` at the top of the jumbotron and pull your hair out trying to customize padding for that!

[Example Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/psKtGY7g15#)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding the CSS for the jumbotron, why not just add your own class to the element and style it the way you like with your own CSS? i.e. Don't use Bootstrap's jumbotron class at all - just style it "from scratch".

Comment: unfortunately, that won't work because of the specificity mentioned in my answer - see an example: http://www.bootply.com/XpnV5r1X9E

Comment: I'm suggesting not using jumbotron at all. One could easily make a custom "my-jumbotron" class that meets one's exact styling needs. Then there wouldn't be a need to worry about specificity.

Comment: ah yes, you're right. I thought you meant your own class that gets added to jumbotron.